# hivecontext in spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hiveql, hivecontext

I am trying to use hivecontext in spark. The following statements are running fine :

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
```

But, when i run the below statement,

```
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (key INT, value STRING)")
```

I get the following error :

Java Package object not callable

what could be the problem?

Comment: This typically mean missing JVM dependencies but there is not enough information here to tell anything more. What is the rest of the code? How did you obtain binaries? How do you run it?

Comment: I concur with @zero323 Your question lacks of information that makes it salvageable. I'm voting to close it !

Comment: I have taken this from the documentation itself. I wanted to see if this works for me before I use my own dataset with hivecontext.